# DLL troubleshooting tools

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dll

[The official documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815065) is outdated; it pertains to the 6.0 version. I can't find Dependency Walker, nor Dll Universal Problem Solver in my computer, also Visual Studio GUI -> Tools doesn't mention these mini-programs. It's surprising, because they seem to be very useful. How it's managed nowadays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency Walker is a separate product now http://dependencywalker.com/

Installsite also has a list of tools (although some are out of date):
http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/tt_app.htm